# Входные параметры для windows service

Tags: windows-service

Подскажите как лучше всего организовать хранение и передачу входных параметров (данные для подключения к БД, адрес сервера) для службы (windows service)?

Где их лучше всего хранить чтобы можно было оперативно менять, а саму службу только перезапускать и она входе при перезапуске получала эти параметры?

Comment: службу пишите сами?

Comment: Да, службу пишу сам, нахожусь на этапе ее проектирования

Comment: Спасибо за конструктивное обсуждение, получил много нужных ответов!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

использование параметров для старта службы

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    base.OnStart(args);
    var val1 = args[0];
    var val2 = args[1];
    ...
    var valn = args[n];
}
```

хранить параметры в строке параметров запуска в оснастке служб

дабы небыло вопросов про шифрование строчек подключения и тд, каждой службе своего доменного юзера

**UPD:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заполнить строчку "Параметры запуска"

**UPD2:**

пользователя так же можно задать в оснастке

Comment: Как их передавать из вне на вход?

Comment: сейчас скриншот сделаю

Comment: @Артем обновил ответ

Comment: Думаю так. Организую авторизацию к БД по доменной учетной записи из под которой работает служба, соответственно данные о пользователе не надо передавать, остается адрес сервера и схема в БД, для этих двух параметров, как мне кажется, удачно подходит перечисление параметров запуска как на снимке экрана. Спасибо за ответы!